# No *reputation* from upvotes - is this a bug?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I recently answered a question with a bounty [Floating a ping pong ball in the air just using a pen!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69731/floating-a-ping-pong-ball-in-the-air-just-using-a-pen/70371#70371), received 4 upvotes, and was awarded the bounty; I got +150 karma from the bounty as usual, but have not got any *reputation* from the upvotes.

Is this a bug, or a feature limiting *reputation* from upvotes that I missed reading about in the FAQ?

Comment: Ha ha, the term karma made me chuckle :-D

Comment: @Dilaton It's a term from [reddit](http://reddit.com). I think Hacker News also uses it. Not sure.

Comment: Even I was confused by that word "karma". . Didn't know it's an English word.

Comment: I believe it's Sanskrit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, it's "reputation", not "karma" ;-)

Basically, that post is (was) in [Community Wiki mode](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki). It does not accrue reputation.

Comment: Wrong website. ;)

Also, thanks.